# Non-inverting amplifier with offset

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, voltage-reference, non-inverting

I have a non-inverting amplifier circuit shown in picture. This circuit has an input wave (-/+ 5V) and output needs to be 0 to 3.3V. I'll be using zener diode (LM 385) as my voltage reference. But I don't really know how zener diodes work. And I will need to decide the resistor values as well. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it, whether a link, or suggestion to the circuit itself, I appreciate it.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Which version of the LM385 are you using? There's an version adjustable between 1.25V and 5.3V, and fixed voltage versions such as 1.25 and 2.5V. There may well be others.

Comment: This circuit won't work for inputs less than +2.5V, because the reference diode must always be reversed biased.

Comment: Maybe first try using a voltage source instead of D1.  Once you get your expected output from the rest of the circuit, then work on making a offset reference that works with your circuit.

Comment: I am using LM385-2.5V. My input is 5V so I think I'm good with that. I already got my desired output using just a voltage source(6.67V), but this diode(2.5V) is what I have available.

Answer (score 1):

A simple resistive divider may be good enough here, optionally followed by a buffer amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTIIzt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>